# Dwarf Umbrella Plant Drooping

Tags: houseplants, indoors, diseases, plant-care

My umbrella plant suddenly started drooping. The leaves at the bottom drooped first and then the ones at the top. Now the whole plant has drooped. Is there any way I can bring back the plant? What has caused this?[image: Drooped plant]

Comment: Is this the Schefflera you already asked about, or a different one?

Comment: Hey, I’m posting this for the first time. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so sorry - didnt have the right glasses on when I first looked and there's a question below posted by someone else whose name begins with A on the same plant! Apologies - does the pot its growing in have a drainage hole?

Comment: @Bamboo No worries. :) Yes, it does have holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plant has root rot from overwatering.  The circulation system has collapsed  so the leaves are not getting water.

Remove the plant from the existing pot and put in a pot with drainage.  Move to higher light and cut back the plant to six inches above the soil.  Wait and it should bud out in a month or so

originally this plant comes from south east Asia so it can handle hot temperatures.  It should be watered when the top inch of soil is dry to the touch

Comment: Thank you so much. I’m living in Dubai and it’s summer here. The temperature goes near to 50C. Can the plant withstand such climate? How often should I water it?